# Hide "foreach" results if there is only one result

Tags: php, foreach

I have post type with an "email" custom field.
When editing a post, I would like to know if other posts have the same email value.

So, I created the following function :

```
function samemailaddress($field){ 
    
$emailcurrentpost = get_field('email');
$referencecurrentpost = get_field('reference');
    
    echo '<table>';

global $post;
$tmp_post = $post;
$args = array( 
        'post_type' => 'reservation',
        'posts_per_page' => '-1',);
$myposts = get_posts( $args );

    foreach( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post);
    
            $reference = get_field('reference');
            $email = get_field('email');

    
        if($email === $emailcurrentpost) {
            ?>
    <tr>
  <td><?php echo $reference; ?></td>
  </tr>
    
<?php   }
        
endforeach;
$post = $tmp_post;

echo '</table>';

 }
```

If no other post has the same value, it will only display the current post. If the current post is the only result, then I'd like to hide the whole table.

Of course I could create a condition to hide the current post no matter the number of results, but i'd rather keep it (it allows me to compare the current post with other results)

Answer (score 0):

Why not prevent your existing post from coming back in the $myposts query...

```
$args = array( 
  'post_type' => 'reservation',
  'posts_per_page' => '-1',
  'exclude' => [$tmp_post->ID]
);
```

Comment: I guess I misunderstood you question. Sorry